# How can I get attachments to work if I don't have threads on my lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

there are a few lens attachments (fisheye and pinhole) that I would love to have, but my one lens doesn't have threads that I could use to attach the fisheye/pinhole. Is there any way I could still attach these, or would it just be worth buying a whole lens? The camera I use is a Nikon D3000, and currently I'm using the lens it came with the most, 18mm-55mm, (which is the one that doesn't have threads) but I also have an AF-S Nikkor-Zoom 55mm-200mm that HAS threads, but I don't use that one nearly as much. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Get your threads back by removin the filter that is already on the lens! Generally lenses without threads lack them for vignetting reasons and some accept slip-in filters at the rear.

Answer (score 2):

The kit D3000 comes with the 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G AF-S DX VR Nikkor Zoom Lens I believe. According to the [Nikon website](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2176/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-55mm-f%252F3.5-5.6G-VR.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) it accepts 52mm screw-on filters. You should have no problem adding 52mm screw on filters or attachments such as macro filters or wide angle lenses([example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VSM7LE)).

If you have multiple lenses that you would like these attachments to work with, you can get step up/step down rings that let you use other thread sizes together. For example you could get a step up from a 52mm filter to a 77mm filter and use 77mm attachments on multiple lenses.

Note that these lens attachments many times come with severe trade-offs as far as quality goes, but they are very inexpensive typically. The other option would be to get a dedicated lens for fisheye or macro work.

Answer (score 1):

There are some clip on attachments. I have a Raynox dcr-250 which is a clip on macro adapter, quality is undoubtedly less than a dedicated macro lens but then the price is also considerably less and its "good enough".

You will need to worry about clearance between the attachment and your lens, I bought it for my Nikon P7100 along with a Polaroid adapter tube which extends just beyond maximum lens reach so that macro lens and camera lens do not collide.